# How to use flexbox to put an space between ::before icon and text?

Tags: html, css

How to use `flexbox` to put a space between Icon (Icon created by the pseudo-element `before`) and text?

```css
.design .text ul li {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.design .text ul li::before {
  font-family: "font awesome 5 free";
  content: "\f108";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Responsive Design</li>
  <li>Modern And Clean Design</li>
  <li>Clean Code</li>
  <li>Browser Friendly</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: FYI: Do note that font icons pose a critical issue for accessibility as they can't be really made accessible for screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox [in combination with gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) (this is also supported for flexbox, not only for grid) to space elements.

In the example I just used "a" as an example for the content, this can of course also be your font icon.

Note that if you need the bullet point from the li, you can wrap the content inside your list with an additional div or span to get both to be displayed.

```css
ul li {
  padding: 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

li::before {
  content: "a";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Responsive Design</li>
  <li>Modern And Clean Design</li>
  <li>Clean Code</li>
  <li>Browser Friendly</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your ul element the property gap. Then add margin-right to you `ul li::before` css.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}
ul li {  
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li::before {
  font-family: "font awesome 5 free";
  content: " \f108 ";
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Responsive Design</li>
  <li>Modern And Clean Design</li>
  <li>Clean Code</li>
  <li>Browser Friendly</li>
</ul>
```